# iOS Launch Image Works in Dev but not App Store Version

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, splash-screen, launchimage

I have an iOS app and I am trying to get the launch screen to work properly. It works fine when I run the app in the simulator or on-device via xCode. But after I upload the binary to the App Store the splash screen image stops working.

I am using Cordova and `cordova-plugin-splashscreen`.

It looks like it's still trying to load it and comes up with the spinner but the image doesn't appear.

What can cause differences between a local run and an App Store build?

This is what the broken App Store version looks like on initial boot. It eventually does end up loading properly and the app runs fine. But it looks horrible while loading.

[image: broken image in App Store version]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you build and run on local device, you are building using the "Run" scheme, whereas when you build your app for the App Store you use the "Profile" scheme. The Build Configuration for the Run scheme is called "Debug" whereas the build configuration for the Profile scheme is called "Release".

In order to fix the problem and achieve parity, you need to change the build configuration for the Run scheme to "Release". You do that in this way:

- Click on the app icon next to the play button on the top left in XCode.
- Select "Edit Scheme".
- Click on "Run" in the left pane.
- Change Build Configuration to "Release".
- Close.
- Build and Run.

In theory, your app should now run as it does when downloaded from the app store.

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a try and see if it's spitting out any errors or anything else that helps debug my issue!

Answer (score 0):

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kXdzk3qhCWc&list=PLt2cCXacqzgfUAjHYnZ9rrPkih4NzAV4E&index=8&t=94s
```

I think you need to satisfy the Apple about your launch assets
as shown in above video link may help you. If i understand properly your question.

Thank you.